# NuGet package install that inserts CallTarget nodes in the AfterBuild Target

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, target

I've built a NuGet package that packages managed and unmanaged dependencies, some of which are runtime dependencies, and so I have several Targets in my .targets file for the NuGet file which copy those dependencies to the bin folder of the project consuming the NuGet package, and I'd like for the consumer to not have to insert the `CallTarget` nodes in their .csproj file manually.

My package's .targets file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"> 
  <Target Name="CopyDeviceIntegrationNativeDependencies"> 
    <Message Text="Copying Device Integration native dependencies to $(OutDir)..." Importance="high" />
    <ItemGroup> 
      <TDDeviceIntegrationNativeDependencies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Packages\TDDeviceIntegration*\lib\native\**\*.*" /> 
    </ItemGroup> 
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TDDeviceIntegrationNativeDependencies)" DestinationFiles="@(TDDeviceIntegrationNativeDependencies->'$(OutDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" ></Copy> 
  </Target> 
  <Target Name="CopyDeviceIntegrationContentDependencies">
      <Message Text="Copying Device Integration content dependencies to $(OutDir)..." Importance="high" />
      <ItemGroup>
          <TDDeviceIntegrationContentDependencies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Packages\TDDeviceIntegration*\content\**\*.*" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Copy SourceFiles="@(TDDeviceIntegrationContentDependencies)" DestinationFiles="@(TDDeviceIntegrationContentDependencies->'$(OutDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')" ></Copy>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CopyDeviceIntegrationManagedDependencies">
      <Message Text="Copying Device Integration managed dependencies to $(OutDir)..." Importance="high" />
      <ItemGroup>
          <TDDeviceIntegrationManagedDependencies Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\Packages\TDDeviceIntegration*\lib\*.*" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Copy SourceFiles="@(TDDeviceIntegrationManagedDependencies)" DestinationFiles="@(TDDeviceIntegrationManagedDependencies->'$(OutDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)')"></Copy>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

My consuming .csproj file needs to have this in it for those copies to happen:

```xml
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <CallTarget Targets="CopyDeviceIntegrationNativeDependencies" />
    <CallTarget Targets="CopyDeviceIntegrationContentDependencies" />
    <CallTarget Targets="CopyDeviceIntegrationManagedDependencies" />
  </Target>
```

Considering the fact that there can only be one `AfterBuild` target in this .csproj file (as far as I know), is there anyway that I can insert those `CallTarget` nodes for the consumer upon installation of the NuGet package so that the consumer doesn't have to add those in manually?  I've never run across a NuGet package that forces the consumer to have to make changes to their .csproj file after installation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make all of the targets hook into the build themselves, not requiring any changes by project authors:

```
<Target Name="Foo" AfterTargets="AfterBuild"> …
```

Note that it looks like you just want to include files to the output directory, which can be done without targets as static item groups:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)path\relativetotargetsfile\somecontent\**"
      Link="\%(Filename)%(Extension)"
      Visible="false"
      CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This will support incremental build. Change the `Link` metadata if you need the content to be put into subdirectories.

Comment: I think the first suggestion is the cleanest.  Would you agree?  To clarify, the second suggestion would go in the .csproj file, requiring a manual step by the consumer still, correct?

Comment: I was thinking into a `build\PackageName.targets` file so it will be automatically imported into the consuming projects

Comment: An example would be the [targets file packed with Grpc.Core](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/941dbaf9f0adb99f3fac4317c703084409a7a33d/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Grpc.Core.targets)

Comment: Oh wow okay, that also would work.  Do you see an advantage of one over the other?

Comment: All tooling will see it as items to output so it should work well across project references. Incremental build also works with `PreserveNewest` for the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata, the `<Copy>` task would have to be amended to make it incremental (= avoid excessive copying during incremental build)

Comment: I tried the second approach and it didn't work for me.  After building the solution, I only got the dlls that are explicitly referenced in the csproj :(

Comment: you can use binary logs (`/bl` argument) of msbuild 15 and the [Structured Log Viewer](http://msbuildlog.com) to debug the build. note that `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` will point to the current target file's directory so if it's inside the nuget package, the path needs to be relative inside that package (which is super useful for the new `PackageReference` way of referencing NuGet packages)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166978/discussion-between-jake-smith-and-martin-ullrich).

Comment: For me, the Link attribute had to look like this: `Link="$(Filename)$(Extension)`